# Using Wolfram to Compare "env" (shell command) Outputs

Tags: grid-layouts

Suppose on **SystemOne** the `env` shell command produces a string output like

```
VAR1=value1
VAR3=value3
```

while on **SystemTwo** the the `env` command produces something like

```
VAR1=valueA
VAR2=valueB
```

and we would like to compare these two outputs by producing a `TextGrid` along the lines of:

```
|      | SystemOne | SystemTwo |
|------+-----------+-----------|
| VAR1 | value1    | valueA    |
| VAR2 |           | valueB    |
| VAR3 | value3    |           |
```

**Question:** What is a way to do this with Mathematica, perhaps in the form of a function `envCompare[..]`?

**Attempt.**

First we can let `envSystemOne` and `envSystemTwo` denote the initial output strings of running `env` on each of the two systems. We can then define

```
listToRule[str_] := Module[{split, rule},
  split = StringSplit[str, "="];
  split[[1]] -> StringJoin[Drop[split, 1]]]
```

as a helper function for

```
envSystemOneAssoc = <|
  "SystemOne" -> 
   Association[
    listToRule /@ 
     StringSplit[envSystemOne, "\n"]]|>
envSystemTwoAssoc = <|
  "SystemTwo" -> 
   Association[listToRule /@ StringSplit[envSystemTwo, "\n"]]|>
```

associations which now take form

```
<|"SystemOne" -> <|"VAR1" -> "value1", "VAR3" -> "value3"|>|>
<|"SystemTwo" -> <|"VAR1" -> "valueA", "VAR2" -> "valueB"|>|>
```

The last step is marshalling this into a TextGrid somehow.

Answer (score 1):

One can use `RemoteConnect` to log in to the two Linux machines.
You have to change IP numbers and user names and passwords and you may improve the code a bit (sorry, a bit ad hoc), but it just works.

```
rc1 = RemoteConnect["192.168.178.12","USERNAME1","PASSWORD1"];
rc2 = RemoteConnect["192.168.178.151","USERNAMe","PASSWORD2"];
op  = RightComposition[
  RemoteRunProcess[#,"env"][["StandardOutput"]]&,
  ImportString[#,"Table","FieldSeparators"->"="]&,
  Cases[#,{s_String/;StringLength[s]>1,_String}]&
];
lists = ((SplitBy[#, First]& @ Sort[Flatten[(Thread/@MapIndexed[(#2[[1]]->op[#1] )&,{rc1,rc2}])/. (i_Integer -> {e_,v_}) :>{e,i,v},1]]
)/.{ {{s_String,1,v_String}} :> {{s,1,v},{s,2,""}},{{s_String,2,v_String}} :> {{s,1,""},{s,2,v}}}
)/. {{s_,1,v1_},{s_,2,v2_}} :> {s, v1, v2};
TextGrid[Prepend[lists,{"","SystemOne","SystemTwo"}],Frame->All]
```